# How do I remove a document from a collection in DocumentDb?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'd like to delete a specific document in DocumentDb. I can't find a reference to a DELETE or REMOVE syntax. Could someone tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 5):

In C#, you can delete using self-links ...

```
using (var client = new DocumentClient(EndPoint, AuthKey))
{
    await client.DeleteDocumentAsync("SELFLINK");
}
```

If you want to delete by your own IDs, this doesn't seem to be currently possible.

Discussion page is here:

http://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6333050-it-should-be-possible-to-remove-a-document-by-id

Comment: Does this mean I first need to query it and create a document from my query result then use selflink to delete that document?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the documentId, you can use `CreateDocumentUri` rather than doing a query to get the self link. In most common cases you will already have the id of a document you want to delete.

```cs
using (var client = new DocumentClient(EndPoint, AuthKey))
{
    Uri documentUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(databaseId, collectionId, docId);
    await client.DeleteDocumentAsync(documentUri);
}
```